# Rails: Fedena webpage has a redirect loop error. No method error undefined method config_value for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have installed fedena (rails application) in my website

http://www.technoadmin.com/

i have installed all plugins, gems, created and migrated the db.

i have created the symbolic link like this

```
ln -s ~/fedena/public ~/public_html
```

when visiting my webpage it shows

This webpage has a redirect loop

so please help me. i am a newbie.i have tried to install this
application for the last
one month. i think i have reached the final step. so please help me to
solve this error.i will be very thankful to you.

and my production logfile is

```
# Logfile created on Fri Jul 26 14:55:03 +0530 2013

Processing UserController#login (for 182.73.241.18 at 2013-07-26 15:00:48) [GET]
  Parameters: {"action"=>"login", "controller"=>"user"}
[FedenaRescue] No method error undefined method `config_value' for nil:NilClass

NoMethodError (undefined method `config_value' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:319:in `set_user_language'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `send'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `evaluate_method'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:225:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:629:in `run_before_filters'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:615:in `call_filters'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_without_flash'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:146:in `perform_action'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `send'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process_without_filters'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:437:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:93:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:321:in `start_request_handler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:275:in `send'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:270:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:149:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:219:in `spawn_rails_application'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:214:in `spawn_rails_application'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:213:in `spawn_rails_application'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:132:in `spawn_application'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99

Redirected to http://technoadmin.com/user/dashboard
```

These are the lines from 310 to 325 and i have only 325 lines in my application_controller.rb

```
return @local_tzone_time
  end

  private
  def set_user_language
    lan = Configuration.find_by_config_key("Locale")
    I18n.default_locale = :en
    Translator.fallback(true)
    if session[:language].nil?
      I18n.locale = lan.config_value
    else
      I18n.locale = session[:language]
    end
    News.new.reload_news_bar
  end
end
```

Comment: please fix formatting

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with a method called `config_value`

```
NoMethodError (undefined method config_value' for nil:NilClass): app/controllers/application_controller.rb:319:inset_user_language'
```

so check your `application_controller.rb` on line 319 and post what's there

EDIT:

in your code (line 319), you're calling `config_value` on `lan` - but the error message is saying that `lan` has a nil value - so config_value can't be called on it.

earlier you have `lan = Configuration.find_by_config_key("Locale")` - so i'm guessing that rails can't find a config_key called "Locale" - but really I'm not sure.  Did you write this code or was it generated by a gem?

Comment: I18n.locale = lan.config_value

Comment: check out the formatting page that i linked above and post lines 310-330 from your application_controller in your main post

Comment: dax i have posted the code in my main post please help me to solve the error

Comment: it was generated by a gem. actually it is an application called fedena (a school erp) and i tried install on site5

Comment: can you able to guess what is the error is and how can i solve it? please...............

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when trying to setup Fedena on Ubuntu 20.04 using Docker.

Each time I try accessing the application on my browser on http://server-address:8080:/user/dashboard, I get a redirection. And then on my console, I get the error:

```
web_1  | Processing UserController#dashboard (for 103.89.5.96 at 2020-10-25 18:33:15) [GET]
web_1  |   Parameters: {"controller"=>"user", "action"=>"dashboard"}
web_1  | [FedenaRescue] No method error undefined method `config_value' for nil:NilClass
web_1  | 
web_1  | NoMethodError (undefined method `config_value' for nil:NilClass):
web_1  |   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:342:in `set_user_language'
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

**Note**: This is a temporary fix as I did not have a lot of time to dig into the codebase.

The issue emanates from this code in the `app/controllers/application.rb` file:

```
private

def set_user_language
  lan = Configuration.find_by_config_key('Locale')
  I18n.default_locale = :en
  Translator.fallback(true)
  I18n.locale = if session[:language].nil?
                  lan.config_value
                else
                  session[:language]
                end
  News.new.reload_news_bar
end
```

I presume that the action `set_user_language` tries to set up a language for the user based on the default locale language set up on his/her machine/application or the session language, but then the `config_value` method called on `Ian` in `lan.config_value` seems to be `Nil`.

And this causes the redirect error since it is invoked in the `app/controllers/application.rb` using a `before_filter`:

```
before_filter :set_user_language
```

So it is called/invoked before any action is completed in the application.

A temporary fix will be to comment out the `before_filter` for it defined at the top of the `app/controllers/application.rb` file:

```
# before_filter :set_user_language
```

Now you can try accessing the page again.

You can as well consider running the command `rake db:seed` to seed the data in the `db/seed.rb` file into the database since it contains some important data that the application will need in order to run smoothly. And it also seems to contain the `config_value` data for the **Configuration**.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**